# Determine rails environment from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a rails gem, in which I have some logic that I'd like to be conditional based on the rails environment.

The following code errors out:

```
if Rails.env.production?
```

When running in the test app this gives me:

```
undefined method .env for Gemname::Rails::Module
```

So, how do you find the Rails environment from a method call in a module that's in a gem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `Rails` module in your project, and the constant lookup is finding it, rather than the top-level Rails module. You can either use the top-level constant:

```
::Rails.env.production?
```

Or you can just check the environment variable:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV']
```

Comment: Of course, thank you! (10 minutes before S.O. will let me accept your answer.)